# Never showing any symptoms

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, medical

I am looking for the word for someone who never shows any symptoms of a disease. I am *not* looking for the word asymptomatic.

Asymptomatic is often used for people who initially display no symptoms but go on to develop symptoms as the disease progresses.

I have read a medical report with this term in it but I can't remember it.

---

Note: The following was added to this question only *after* the first answer was provided.

---

I remember reading it as: [something]symtomacis and [something]-symtomatic. for example - wordsymtomatic and word-symtomatic.

Found it! The word is paucisymptomatic. Also written pauci-symptomatic.

Comment: Non-symptomatic doesn’t work?

Comment: I've understood that *asymptomatic* means someone who doesn't experience or display any symptoms of the disease.

Comment: " who initially display no symptoms but go on to develop symptoms" that's the *incubation* period, that has little to do with people with asymptomatic disease.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too but I read in a medical journal another word that they defined as meaning never displaying any symptoms. They said "asymptomatic" can also mean someone who didn't initially exhibit symptoms whereas this word means they are, as you say, a carrier. I really wish I could find that research again on Google scholar.

Comment: I think this is more a medical question than an English Language one. Are there such people who NEVER show symptoms?

Comment: I read in a medical journal this word that they defined as meaning never displaying any symptoms. They said "asymptomatic" can also mean someone who didn't initially exhibit symptoms but went on to exhibit some (however mild). Whereas this word means they are, a "carrier" and don't display any symptoms at all. I really wish I could find that research again on Google scholar.

Comment: [*Silent spreaders can be divided into three categories*: **asymptomatic**, **presymptomatic** *and very* **mildly symptomatic**.](https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2020/04/13/831883560/can-a-coronavirus-patient-who-isnt-showing-symptoms-infect-others)

Comment: You seem to be on a wild goose chase.Your understanding of "asymptomatic" seems faulty - it does not depend on duration. You can be asymptomatic today and show symptoms tomorrow, or  be asymptomatic today and never show symptoms, i.e. permanently asymptomatic.A disease or condition can also be asymptomatic (=clinically silent.). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Mallon

Comment: FOUND IT! It's "pauci-symptomatic". Also written, paucisymptomatic. Here is a link to the report that mentions it https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-020-0883-7?fbclid=IwAR156AOapdnJ9R8QG4s5odlVrQgA9nhbQV7OU1KDttNw4Pq7Y860hRd54B4

Comment: I updated your question so it's obvious that you hadn't been asking for *[something]symtomcis* at the time that @lumbrjak provided an answer. Otherwise, if it had been there, that answer would have clearly not been what was asked for—and could produce downvotes. At the time the question was asked, *carrier* was a perfectly reasonable response. Generally speaking, you don't want to edit questions in a way that invalidates any existing answers.

Comment: *Paucisymptomatic* seems to be an odd word to use for somebody showing **no** symptoms, for which there is already a perfectly good word *asymptomatic*. One would expect *paucisymptomatic* to be used for somebody who is showing a **few** symptoms of the disease (perhaps not enough to satisfy the usual diagnostic criteria for it, but still some).

Comment: 'Paucisymptomatic' might be the answer you've been looking for, but as per your question, it's wrong. Check the definition.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no research and  offers/accepts an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Asymptomatic** means simply "not exhibiting any symptoms **at the current time**".  It does not even even imply (absent context suggesting otherwise) that one is infected, and someone who *is* infected might be "asymptomatic" at one point and later become "symptomatic" (and hence no longer "asymptomatic").  Or someone (a "typhoid Mary") could have an infection for days, weeks, months, years and remain "asymptomatic" the entire time.

**Paucisymptomatic**, on the other hand, means having few symptoms ("pauci" meaning "a few").  It does not imply having no symptoms at all.  And, as with "asymptomatic", it doesn't imply anything about past or future conditions, only the present state.

Comment: To paraphrase a comment I made under the question, this answer is *clearly* not what was asked for. The question very specifically says, "I am *not* looking for the word asymptomatic." If you want to ignore the question and provide this as an answer *anyway*, you need to give better guidance as to why no other answer could be possibly correct. (Such as *carrier* from the other answer, which actually is a word that isn't *asymptomatic*.) And also, after the latest round of edits, you need to say why *paucisymptomatic* can not possibly be correct either.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "paucisymptomatic" means having a paucity of symptoms, not none at all.

Comment: Better. But why is **carrier** obviously not the right answer either? If you're going to go against the specific request for a word in the question, it seems there's a lot more onus on you to argue against any answer other than what you provide. Actually being *immune* to it (as in the definition of *carrier*) seems like a stronger word than just *asymptomatic*,  which, as you yourself say, means only not having symptoms *in the moment*. The question asked about *never* showing symptoms.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "Carrier" doesn't (rigorously) imply anything about the presence or absence of symptoms.  Someone who has the disease but no symptoms would be referred to as an "asymptomatic carrier" (look it up).

Comment: The very definition of **carrier**, as already provided in the other answer, but also from [this link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carrier), clearly does say exactly that in some cases. If you are *immune* to something it's not possible to ever have any symptoms.

Comment: @JasonBassford - What do you think "a bearer and transmitter of a causative agent of an infectious disease" means?  The "especially" clause is identifying a subset of the "bearers and transmitters" -- it's not exclusive.

Comment: The definition is of the ***causative*** *agent*. Just because something is *causative* doesn't mean that it produces symptoms. I can carry a virus in my bloodstream, meaning I can pass it on to others, but if I'm personally immune to it, then I will never be affected by it myself. But don't argue with me in comments, include all of this in proper detail in your answer. Or, even better, explain not only why the answer to the question should not be **carrier**, but also not actually **immunity** or **immune**.

Comment: As I've said, you have *deliberately* chosen to provide an answer that was asked to be ***excluded***. So, you have a much greater onus to provide more detail than you would if you had suggested something that wasn't prohibited.

Comment: Yes, Jason is quite correct here. This is really abusing the site;  the correction 'Asymptomatic means simply "not exhibiting any symptoms at the current time" ' should be given as a 'comment'. Preferably with a linked reference. And certainly with a C-V.

Answer (score 3):

***Carrier***
From Merriam-Webster unabridged

a person, animal, or plant that harbors and transmits the causative agent of an infectious disease; especially :  one who carries the causative agent systemically but is asymptomatic or immune to it

The infamous [Typhoid Mary](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3959940/) is an example of a carrier of the causative agent of Typhoid fever.

Comment: That isn't the word I remember reading it was [something]symtomacis and can be written [something]-symtomatic. But thank you very much, "carrier" does help

Comment: Thank you I found the word. It is paucisymptomatic!

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that at the time you answered it, this was a reasonable answer. Without my note, and before I checked the question's edit history, I had been thinking of downvoting this answer because I had assumed  it clearly isn't what had been asked for. However, given that the updated criteria weren't there when you provided this answer, it's probably what I would have given myself (+1).

Comment: @Jason Much obliged for the attention to detail. I was the first to answer and figured I'd nailed it according to the question at the time.

Comment: Although the asymptomatic caveat is not a required part of the definition of 'carrier', the 'especially' here would seem to make this the default sense, so a/the correct answer.